# How to get the equation value result using Highcharts-Regression?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using this plugin https://github.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression , I am able to draw a regression line and output the result like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/4mauwxvy/

I want to get the equation result

```
Equation: y=2x^2 + -4x +3
```

and save it to Javascript variable. I dont find any option to get the value from the regression function. How to achieve that?

Comment: example not working

Comment: @A.RAZIK it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the demo below. Is it an output which you want to get?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2gsqk1z0/

```
  events: {
    load: function() {
       let chart = this;
                
                
       console.log(chart.legend.allItems[1].name);

       output = chart.legend.allItems[1].name;
                
       console.log(output)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice trick, do you also know how to output the equations that are displayed on the regression line?

Comment: @gameon67 I am not sure if I understood your question well. Would you like to display the output in the custom way?